# Mocking ErrorHandler in Angular for rethrown throwError (jasmine)

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

Using Jasmine I have some tests which are in place to handle error logic from a subscribed Observable.

```
    this.apiService
      .post({})
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        catchError((e) => {
          return throwError(() => e);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(() => {});
```

The intention is that the error is rethrown so it can be handled outside of the component in a custom error handler.

```
Chrome Headless 109.0.5412.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  [object Object] thrown
  [object Object] thrown
  [object Object] thrown
```

I initially tried to override the `ErrorHandler` with a spy but it produced no effect.

Also tried to use the `jasmine.spyOnGlobalErrorsAsync` which seemed to still produce the errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch those nested unhandled exceptions from inside observables by using fakeAsync with flush or tick inside a try-catch block.

```
it("should raise uncaught exception on service error", fakeAsync(() =>
{
  // Arrange
  apiServiceSpy.post.and.returnValue(throwError(() => new Error("Failed service call")));

  // Act
  component.methodThatSubscribesToApiServicePost();
  let error: unknown = undefined;
  try
  {
      flush();
  }
  catch (ex)
  {
      error = ex;
  }

  // Assert
  expect(error?.message).toBe("Failed service call");
}));
```

Your custom global ErrorHandler (i.e. CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler) you would unit test separately.